# ReactJS Updating Classes

Tags: reactjs

i'm very new to ReactJS and am trying to update one of my classes when a button is pressed. The program is a fitness app that shows data to the user dependant on directory.
say for example: male - 1 - video.mp4 / male - 2 - video.mp4

Currently, if the user is on video 1 and wants to move to video 2, they will press the next button. This button needs to update the class to display the correct video and text. I've tried using javascript:

```
document.getElementById("pageTitle").innerHTML = pageTitle;
document.getElementById("tipTitle").innerHTML = tipTitle;
document.getElementById("tipInfo").innerHTML = tipInfo;
```

The correct information is pulled from a text file in each directory along with the video. and when they press next / previous, the directory number is updated:

What I want to do is effectively re-render the class, calling the componentDidMount function again and changing the state of the class to the new information because the global variable for the directory location has been updated when they press the button.

Is there a method in reactJS for this, if not, how could I go about re-calling the componentDidMount function while changing some variables, such as the directory location? I've looked up **setState** but i'm not 100% sure it's what i'm looking for. I know the question may seem a bit vague so please feel free to ask if you need any more information.

Comment: Please read the [React documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html) and you will learn that there is no need to manually manipulate the DOM if the state of your application changes, but that you should rely on the `render` method of a component.

Comment: As zwippie already told you, you should first read the documentation. It is an antipatern to manually manipulate DOM in ReactJS. React uses virtual DOM which than handles DOM manipulation accordingly. You should first comprehend how react works before you can become efficient with it.

Comment: When you've have done what the above comments mention, you can look into using Classnames to add/remove classes based on a given state: https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a component with a state that holds the current video playing and update this state when user clicks on the "next" button. You are manually updating the DOM which defeats the purpose of using React.

```
class MyVideoPlayer extends React.Component{
    component(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = ({currentVideo: "male-1-video.mp4"});
    }

    changeVideo = () => {
        this.setState({currentVideo: next_video_here})
    }

    render() {
        return (
            ... your video player here ...
            <button onClick={this.changeVideo}>NEXT</button>
        )
    }
}
```

Do something like this.

Answer (score 0):

I think @Franz Palngipang has a good idea how this page could be implemented using ReactJS. I'll try to clear up a few things you sound confused about. componentDidMount is only called after the first time render is called on that component. This happens immediately after render is finished. componentDidUpdate could be what you are looking for; this is also called after render but this happens after every render. Whenever you call setState in your code, it will also call render (and therefore also calling componentDidUpdate). So imagine what happens if you unconditionally call setState inside of componentDidUpdate (you will get an infinite loop). In your render method, you can use if statements or other conditions (maybe based on this.state or this.props) to return/generate different HTML.